# How can I style future post?

Tags: wp-query, post-status

I'm showing published and future posts on a category page.
I need to make future posts unclickable and add a special class to them in order to add a gray overlay, meaning the post is upcoming..
trying something like

```
$post_status = get_post_status($post_id);
            if($post_status === 'future')
```

doen't work at all..How can I, inside the same loop, disable a link and add a class if post status is "future" ??

any help would be appreciated ..

Here is the first part of my loop (it's a premium theme, and I'm building a custom category page in a child theme)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'post',
    'post_status' => array('publish','future'),
    'showposts' => -1,
        'category'          => get_queried_object_id(), // Current category id
        'category__in'      => array( get_queried_object_id() )
    );



$query= new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        $counter++;?>
        <?php  if( $counter % 2 == 0 ) :     
            if ('future'===get_post_status() ){
            echo '<div class="td-pb-row future">';
        }else if('publish'===get_post_status() ){
            echo '<div class="td-pb-row">' ;
        } ?>                    
            <div class="td-pb-span6">
                <h3 class="entry-title td-module-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute() ?>">
                        <?php the_title() ?>
                    </a>

                </h3>
                <?php the_content();?>
            </div>

            <div class="td-module-image td-pb-span6">
                <div class="td-module-thumb">
                    <?php
                    if ( current_user_can('edit_published_posts') ) {
                        edit_post_link('Edit', '', '', '', 'td-admin-edit');
                    }
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="td-image-wrap" title="<?php    the_title_attribute() ?>">
                        <?php   $post_thumbnail_url = '';
                        if( get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null, 'medium_large') != false ) {
                            $post_thumbnail_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null, 'medium_large');
                        } else {
                            $post_thumbnail_url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/no-thumb/medium_large.png';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <img class="entry-thumb" src="<?php echo esc_url($post_thumbnail_url) ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(strip_tags(the_title())) ?>" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: how did you set `$post_id`?

Comment: I grab the code somewhere !! ;)..In fact I don't know how put condition on post status.whithin a wp_Query loop..

Comment: in this case, please post the full code of your WP_Query loop

Comment: yes thank you Michael, I just edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the function [`get_post_status()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_status/). Inside the loop you have access to the Post Id, but if you leave this blank it will use the ID of the current post instead.

So you code will become something like this (not tested yet):

```
<h3 class="entry-title td-module-title">
    <?php if( get_post_status() != 'future' ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute() ?>">
        <?php the_title() ?>
    </a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php the_title() ?>
    <?php } ?>
</h3>
```

The problem in your code might be with the `$counter` variable. The check for post status 'future' is only done for half of the posts, not for all of them, due to the `% 2`. So I think you should get rid of this `$counter` variable.

So to give an example of how you should change your code:

```
<?php if( 'future' == get_post_status() ){
    echo '<div class="td-pb-row future">';
} else {
    echo '<div class="td-pb-row">';
} ?>
```

Comment: thank you very much leendertvb, in fact the modulo is here to display alternate post (once image on left, once on the right)..I'll try your code and give a feedback

Comment: It worked, thank you very much leendertvb: !! you really helped me !

Comment: Great to hear, Good luck!